# Dota 2 6.85 lag spikes

Tags: dota-2

I've been having a problem in which Dota 2 will freeze for a second once every 10-15 seconds. I've looked over the other posts with similar problems but I think my problem is something else. I know the issue isn't graphics, memory, or disk (while watching a game I opened up task manager and all of them peaked at ~50%. The problem isn't their servers because I don't have the problems on my laptop. That would leave the problem as wifi-and when looking at task manager this is the case (I've included a screenshot of task manager while watching a game). It would drop to zero every 10-15 seconds. However, this problem is only for Dota 2; if I'm downloading a game or watching a video, it runs smooth. Its only when I'm playing Dota that there is an issue.

I have a HP Pavilion Elite HPE-257 c-b running Windows 10.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Edit: I guess I didn't make it clear enough that the problem isn't the wifi itself but rather how the wifi and Dota interact. If the problem was the wifi, my laptop would have the same issue (it doesn't). If the problem was with the computers wifi card, then it would consistently perform worse than my laptop. However, it normally functions fine. It is only when I play dota that this problem occurs. I've attached an image of what happens when just downloading a game. As you can see there are no spikes or anything-it is *only* when playing dota that the issue occurs.

[image]

Comment: Just use Ethernet. Gaming on wifi is just not acceptable. (except for MMOs, hearthstone, and games where ping does not matter.)

Comment: Your second screenshot does not prove anything as the scales are different. While downloading the graph shows 32 Mbps whereas your lag peaks only had their maxima at 500Kbps. This means that they probably still happen in the download screenshot but they are buried within the download traffic and don't show up on the graph

Comment: @Contra My point is that the wifi doesn't randomly drop to zero like was suggested but rather it normally works steadily.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://jhshi.me/2014/04/25/how-android-wifi-state-machine-works/) (very technical) investigation of the Android Wifi interface, your peaks can be caused by an android device in your network. Disconnect any android devices from your WiFi AP and see if the problem persists. If so, then it is caused by something else.

Answer (score 0):

So the newest update fixed the problem and the spikes went away. Thank you for trying to help.